# Android: Split string by "\n" as string not as new line

Tags: java, android, string, split

I have a below string which is coming from the server

```
String text = "- 30016264\n- 30014837\n- 30014836\n";
```

When I used to split it like this

```
String[] list = text.split("\n");
```

I got the list like this with length 1

```
list[0] = "- 30016264\n- 30014837\n- 30014836\n";
```

And when I used to split it like this

```
String[] list = text.split("\\n");
```

I got the same list like this with length 1

```
list[0] = "- 30016264\n- 30014837\n- 30014836\n";
```

How do I write the code to split the string on basis of "\n" not the next line?

**NOTE:** This string is coming from the server as it is written here and when I use this server string as `TextView` value, it will display in one single line.

Comment: `String list = text.split("\n");`. Impossible! That does nog even compile.

Comment: @greenapps Corrected the above code!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you input is coming from the server and in this format :

```
- 30016264\n- 30014837\n- 30014836\n
```

Then, in Java it should be represented with double backslash like this :

```
- 30016264\\n- 30014837\\n- 30014836\\n
```

because backslash is a special character in Java, you have to escape it with another backslash.

Then to split with `\\n` you need to use `\\\\n`, why 4 backslashes because like i said before the backslash is special character for that you have to escape each one with another backslash for that you need 4 instead of 2 or 1.

Your solution should look like :

```
String text = "- 30016264\\n- 30014837\\n- 30014836\\n";
String[] split = text.split("\\\\n");
```

**Outputs**

```
- 30016264 
- 30014837
- 30014836
```

Comment: May i know the reason of four `/` ?

Comment: It works. Thanks!

Comment: @VishvaDave each the input contain two backslash to you have to escape each one with backslash for that there are 4 backslashes

Comment: @YCF_L Ok got it thanks!

Comment: you are welcome @MA13

Comment: **Use This Simplest Way**

     String text = "- 30016264\n- 30014837\n- 30014836\n";
            String[] items = text.split("\n");
            for (String item : items)
            {
                System.out.println("string split is = " + item);
            }

Comment: `String text = "- 30016264\\n- 30014837\\n- 30014836\\n";` ???? By Jove... I understand nothing of this! You changed the original string. It was `String text = "- 30016264\n- 30014837\n- 30014836\n";`. Which was perfectly valid. I wonder why OP accepted your answer.

Comment: @greenapps the OP said **How do I write the code to split the string on basis of "\n" not the next line?** also **NOTE: This string is coming from the server as it is written here and when I use this server string as TextView value, it will display in one single line.** so the `\n` is considered as string and not break line, to consider it as a string you have to use double backslash not only one, I think the OP makes a typo in his/her question

Comment: No. OP does not. OP starts with a perfectly valid string. The string comes from the server. No reason to change that. Your answer does not make sense. And the reaction of OP either.

Comment: @greenapps I assume that the OP use `String text = "- 30016264\\n- 30014837\\n- 30014836\\n";
String[] list = text.split("\n");` for that he/she get `list[0] = "- 30016264\n- 30014837\n- 30014836\n";` [take a look at this demo](https://ideone.com/CPeu3j)

Comment: @greenapps note that the OP said that the information come from the server so another reason to makes me assume that he/she don't mean `String text = "- 30016264\n- 30014837\n- 30014836\n";` but `String text = "- 30016264\\n- 30014837\\n- 30014836\\n";` with double backslash

Comment: Wrong assumption. You clearly can see the string OP received from the server. Its a perfectly valid string. Yours by the way is nonsense.

Comment: @greenapps beside if you print `System.out.println("- 30016264\n- 30014837\n- 30014836\n");` you will get multiple lines but if you print `System.out.println("- 30016264\\n- 30014837\\n- 30014836\\n");` you will get `- 30016264\n- 30014837\n- 30014836\n` in one line there are no break-line [take a loot at this demo](https://ideone.com/CwIrtv)

Comment: Yes you are right about what is printed in both cases. With the first one nice lines. With the second one nonsense.

Comment: @greenapps all this happen because it is a trick question :)

Comment: @YCF_L My string is correct and your answer is also correct for my condition. In your demo, string value is generated by java, not coming from the server that's why your demo also works fine.

Comment: @YCF For your edit - No, my solution looks like this when I print `- 30016264\n- 30014837\n- 30014836\n`

Comment: @MA13 Your question is really unclear, in java if you want to print `\n` you have to use a string like this `String s = "\\n";` and not `String s = "\n";` you get it?